# How to identify call void @llvm.dbg.declare instructions in LLVM IR?

Tags: clang, llvm

I am parsing a LLVM IR.
When meeting a `call` instruction, I want to know whether the instruction is
`call void @llvm.dbg.declare(...)`.
How can I identify such specific call instructions?